# IE and Chrome: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ssl, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Hello i have this error with IE and Google chrome in Windows XP but my website work with Windows Seven (all browser) and Firefox (windows XP too)

I learn in internet the problem its caused by ECDSA cipher

VirtualHost:

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/key.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/COMODO_EV_SHA-256_bundle.crt

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```

What is the good cipher for all OS and browser ? Iam on debian 7 and apache
Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) has an excellent article on configuring the ciphers used by Apache. They provide example strings for three different levels of compatibility depending on your needs.

You should also check that your version of Apache supports elliptic curve crypto.  You can find more detail [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/395924/apache2-ssl-with-ecc).

Lastly, try using [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) to check your site for cipher compatibility with various browsers.  It will also provide a grade for your SSL configuration and suggestions for improving it (if needed).

Comment: Thanks for answer my score for SSL Labs is A, this old cipher are secure ? https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Old_backward_compatibility Its not dangerous ?

Comment: No, not dangerous. The low includes three older cipers and is missing one new one (CAMELLIA). If you need to support older browsers it will work just fine.  However, if you don't need to support them  go with Intermediate.